# height of a div to match the height of the viewport

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div like this.

```
<div> ... </div>
```

I want its height to be the height of the view port (not of the page)

is it possible to do this via CSS or do I have to write some javascript ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509589/full-viewport-height-scaling-div-just-css-no-js-possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. CSS percentage height will work as long as the parent element has a height defined.  Assuming this is your markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This CSS will cause the `<div>` to have the full height of the viewport:

```
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you wanted the `<div>` to expand with its content, the CSS would change as follows:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your have set your viewPort to a certain height, you can just give your div `height:100%;`..

Answer (score 0):

If the div is anywhere in the document, you would need to use javascript. With jQuery is quite simple:

```
$("#my-div").height($(window).height());
```